# Exchange 2010 SP3 Update Rollup 8 - Outlook NDR Errors

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, windows-update

Yesterday started to notice issues with one or two Outlook 2013 clients where when users try to send emails to any address, whether internal or external, a NDR would immediately come back:

```
Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

  Subject:  Earlier letter
  Sent: 10/12/2014 08:03

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

  'Joe Bloggs' on 10/12/2014 08:03
        This message could not be sent. Try sending the message again later, or contact your network administrator.  Error is [0x80004005-00000000-00000000].
```

But when using the user's OWA they could send emails fine. After trawling the internet and getting nowhere I looked at the servers event logs which didn't show anything. It was only when I noticed that Exchange SP3 Update Rollup 8 had automatically been installed on the Exchange Server on the morning of the first instance that I started to wonder.

After uninstalling the rollup package the issue has gone away. Just wanted to see if anyone else had experienced this issue with this update package?

Comment: Just read about it this morning...
http://windowsitpro.com/blog/exchange-2010-sp3-ru8-withdrawn-due-bug-mapi-rpc-layer

Comment: @EliadTech - You should make that into an answer and at least quote some of the article discussing the Rollup's issues and withdrawal.  It could help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [WindowsITPro blog](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/exchange-2010-sp3-ru8-withdrawn-due-bug-mapi-rpc-layer) they say that this update created a problem with the MAPI RPC component.
Other mail services (OWA, ActiveSync, etc.) should work properly, because they don't use the faulty component.

The update has been removed from "Microsoft updates".

As they strongly suggest, you better test all updates before applying them to avoid such situations.
Alternatively, if you don't have any special systems, you could just wait for someone else to be the Guinea pig.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've changed the group policy to prevent automatic updates on our exchange server as a result!

Answer (score 0):

Removing Exchange 2010 SP3 Rollup 8 worked for me. Strangely only Outlook 2013 running on Windows 7 (32-bits) had problems with sending mails out. Outlook 2013 on Windows 8.1 (64-bits) was running fine. 
With Rollup 8 removed all Outlook clients are running normally again.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with this month's (December 2014) "Update Rollup 8" Exchange 2010 SP3 update.

KB2986475 "Update Rollup 8-v2 For Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3" was recently posted to Microsoft Update.  Rolling in this update appears to have resolved the issue.